# Problem with mobile auto-test python+appium+selenium

Tags: python, android, selenium, appium, python-appium

I'am new to mobile automation. I thought I got the gist, but I ran into a problem.
An error occurs when using the command send_keys()
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidElementStateException: Message: Cannot set the element to '321785214'. Did you interact with the correct element?

I have a code

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)
# Skip fingerprint
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@bounds='[413,1802][668,1877]']").click()

# Click Continue
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.Button[@content-desc='Continue']").click()

# Click to input phone number
input_phone_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText").click()

input_phone_number_edit = driver.find_element_by_class_name("android.widget.EditText")

# Enter phone number
input_phone_number_edit.send_keys("321785214")
```

And I have code from other mobile app and this code is working

```
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)
# click to Set up later button
set_up_later_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.Button[@content-desc="Set up later"]').click()

input_phone_number = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.view.View[@content-desc="Phone number"]').click()

input_phone_number_edit = driver.find_element_by_class_name('android.widget.EditText')
driver.implicitly_wait(50)

input_phone_number_edit.send_keys('178546128')

driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("Continue").click()
```

I don't know why first code isn't working. I need help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the default send_keys method, you can use the send_keys method provided by the ActionChains class

from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
        actions.send_keys("321785214")
        actions.perform()
```